# How to give equal height between 2 linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have 2 LinearLayouts of Weight1,With 1st Layout,if i add anything it occupies full width instead of half of screen,How to avoid this

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp1.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/Aqua"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subview_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Green"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/insideLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Yellow" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/Aqua"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/DarkGray" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/BlueViolet"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

On adding view tag,it occupies full width instead of half as specified in weight1,What is problem i am making

Comment: I feel since your orientation is vertical and layout_width of linear layout is match parent it occupies complete width. If want it to occupy half of the width then specify some size for layout_width than giving match parent.

Comment: not clear, can you please be more specific ? which linerlayouts you need 50 50 ?

Comment: I am trying to having 2 layouts with 50/50 heights which i attempted by using weight as 1,But if I add any view to one of layouts,it occupies full width,instead of half of width,I am making it clear to you David.

Comment: Kesh,How do i specify height without hardcoding,Is there anyway in xml,Through programmatically,we can do it using DisplayMetrics,I want to do in xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's simplify your problem. The below should work. I recommend to imagine `weight` as a percentage of 100 and so if you want half and half it is 50,50 (if you wanted a third each its 33,33,33). No need for the weightSum they have been removed. You were missing the `layout_height` of `0dip` this is what allows the `weight` to define the space taken.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp1.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks,How To acheive similar sort of partitioning in relative layout?

Comment: It helped a lot in implementing it,Thanks blundell